# Stuck on some translations from natural language to propositional and first order logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

1. *Let $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ be five variables. Write a formula using only these variables and the operators $\lor$, $\land$, and $\lnot$ equivalent to the sentence "At least two and at most three of these variables are true".*

The first thing that came to my mind is that this sentence is self-referential, so it shouldn't be considered a proposition. But I'm probably missing something here.

2. *Translate "A day next month is Sunday" defining the predicates and domain of quantifiers.*

Let $S(x)$ be "$x$ is Sunday". A silly first approach was to define a "convenient" universe of discourse: let $D = \{d : d \text{ is day of the next month}\}$, then the predicate was $\exists x \in D(S(x))$.
But "next month" seemed somewhat open, so this bothered me. Another try was: let $M = \{m : m \text{ is a month of the year}\}$ and $D_m = \{d : \exists m \in M(d \text{ is day of } m)\}$. Thus I could write $\exists x \in D_{m+1}(S(x))$. But I have the sensation that this notation overcomplicates the solution. What do you think? Is there a cleaner way to express this?

Comment: The first part isn't self-referential in any way: "At least two and at most three of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ are true" doesn't talk about itself. The solution, however, is very long and boring: it is a disjunction of conjunctions of the form $c_1x_1 \land c_2x_2 \land c_3x_3 \land c_4x_4 \land c_5x_5$, where the $c_i$ are optional $\lnot$ signs and you list all the ways you can have either $2$ or $3$ of the $x_i$ true and the others false. ...

Comment: The second part is very open-ended:  your ideas sound as good as any, although (depending on the context) you should maybe avoid using set notation and arithmetic (by using predicate symbols and function symbols). Where did you come across these questions?

Comment: Hi, firstly thanks for the first response. The 1st is indeed long and boring. These questions come from a set of exercises in a text from my university. Unfortunately, they have no solutions.

Comment: As of the 2nd part, I thought the solution using the two sets very convoluted, while the simpler one lacks rigor... but I may be trying to overcomplicate, idk. xD

Comment: I see. I can only conjecture that the author of the questions was expecting you to write a verbal description of the solution to the 1st part (as there are 40 different cases to consider) and was deliberately setting up something that is challenging to model in first-order logic in the 2nd part, because it involves a very unnatural use of natural language.